# Kendo UI Angular file upload component fails with large files

Tags: angular, file-upload, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-upload

I am using the Kendo Angular File Upload component within my Angular 7 app.  The back end is ASP.NET core 2.1 hosting a MVC API via Kestrel.  I can get uploads to work for small files.  Larger files (120MB) fail with a 500 (Internal Server Error).  I have used the following DisableRequestSizeLimit attribute on my endpoint controller method:

```
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit, Route("Upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
{
```

Why would large file uploads still fail after using DisableRequestSizeLimit?

Answer (score 1):

For those of you having similar issues, I managed to resolve this by also adding the RequestFormLimits attribute e.g.

```
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit, RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = Int32.MaxValue, ValueLengthLimit = Int32.MaxValue), Route("Upload")]
```

Hope this helps someone.